# How to specify Nested JSON using Langchain

Tags: python, langchain

I am using [StructuredParser](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/output_parsers/types/structured) of Langchain library. I am getting flat dictionary from parser. Please guide me to get a list of dictionaries from output parser.

```py
PROMPT_TEMPLATE = """ 
You are an android developer. 
Parse this error message and provide me identifiers & texts mentioend in error message. 
--------
Error message is {msg}
--------
{format_instructions}
"""

def get_output_parser():
    missing_id = ResponseSchema(name="identifier", description="This is missing identifier.")
    missing_text = ResponseSchema(name="text", description="This is missing text.")

    response_schemas = [missing_id, missing_text]
    output_parser = StructuredOutputParser.from_response_schemas(response_schemas)
    return output_parser


def predict_result(msg):
    model = ChatOpenAI(open_api_key="", openai_api_base="", model="llama-2-70b-chat-hf", temperature=0, max_tokens=2000)
    output_parser = get_output_parser()
    format_instructions = output_parser.get_format_instructions()
    
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template=PROMPT_TEMPLATE)
    message = prompt.format_messages(msg=msg, format_instructions=format_instructions)
    response = model.invoke(message)

    response_as_dict = output_parser.parse(response.content)
    print(response_as_dict)


predict_result("ObjectNotFoundException AnyOf(AllOf(withId:identifier1, withText:text1),AllOf(withId:identifier2, withText:text1),AllOf(withId:identifier3, withText:text1))")
```

The output I get is

```json
{
    "identifier":"identifier1",
    "text":"text1"
}
```

Expected output is

```json
[
    {
        "identifier":"identifier1",
        "text":"text1"
    },
    {
        "identifier":"identifier2",
        "text":"text1"
    },
    {
        "identifier":"identifier3",
        "text":"text1"
    }
]
```

How to specify such nested JSON in OutputParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my ResponseSchema by specifying JSON format in description and it gives me expected result. Below is the code snippet that is working.

```py
formatted_json = ResponseSchema(name="assertions", description='''[{"text":"","identifier":""}]'''
response_schemas = [format_json]
```

I get output as

```json
{"assertions":[
    {
        "identifier":"identifier1",
        "text":"text1"
    },
    {
        "identifier":"identifier2",
        "text":"text1"
    },
    {
        "identifier":"identifier3",
        "text":"text1"
    }
]}
```

Comment: This will be sent to the LLM as [`"assertions": string // [{"text":"","identifier":""}]`](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/1d2aa19aeeca94f21b01c1f3ada6eb5e2defca23/libs/langchain/langchain/output_parsers/structured.py#L14), because "string" is the default type. This might cause the output to be unreliable, and the lack of description might reduce quality further.

Comment: Fine. let me check on different error messages. I hope there would be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

[I'm not sure if it's possible to get a list of objects with StructuredOutputParser](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/1976), but you can definitely get an object of lists. Use the `type` parameter of [`ResponseSchema`](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/1d2aa19aeeca94f21b01c1f3ada6eb5e2defca23/libs/langchain/langchain/output_parsers/structured.py#L24):

```
def get_output_parser():
    missing_id = ResponseSchema(
        name="identifiers",
        description="These are the missing identifiers.",
        type='List[string]'
    )
    missing_text = ResponseSchema(
         name="texts",
         description="These are the missing texts.",
         type='List[string]'
    )

    response_schemas = [missing_id, missing_text]
    output_parser = StructuredOutputParser.from_response_schemas(response_schemas)
    return output_parser
```

Untested, but the output should be

```
{
    "identifiers":["identifier1","identifier2","identifier3"],
    "texts":["text1","text1","text1"]
}
```

If you really need the nested format, you can convert it easily in Python:

```
nested_dict = [{'identifier': i, 'text': t} for i, t in zip(response_as_dict['identifiers'], response_as_dict['texts'])]

#[{'identifier': 'identifier1', 'text': 'text1'},
# {'identifier': 'identifier2', 'text': 'text1'},
# {'identifier': 'identifier3', 'text': 'text1'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. In above case text1 was common across all 3 identifiers. It may be different so pairing may be difficult using python logic. sometimes some identifiers don't have text as well (missing text or null text )

Comment: @HarshIT It should still work, the `missing_text` response schema is also a list. The sample output data was taken from your example.

Comment: Got it. Let me check it for different error messages.